# Username availability checker always returns true

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, linq

When I try to write any name which is available in database it says username is available you can use it. It is not entering the `if` condition. It should be like username is already available you should try other.

```csharp
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public JsonResult Checkusername(string name)
{
    bool UserNameinUse = true;
    var exist =db.Employees.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(name)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (exist == null)
    {
        UserNameinUse = false;
    }
    return Json(UserNameinUse);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtUserName').keyup(function () {
        var divElement = $('#divOutput');
        var userName = $(this).val();
        if (userName.length >= 3) {
            var url = '/Employee/CheckUserName/';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {name: userName },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.UserNameinUse =="false") {
                        divElement.text(userName + 'already Exist Please try with other one!');
                        divElement.css('color', 'red');
                    }
                    else {
                        divElement.text(userName + ' is available you can use this');
                        divElement.css('color', 'green');
                    }
                },
                err: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        }
        else if (userName.length == 0) {
            divElement.text('');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you put the code in the question as text? I'ts easier to help you that way.

Comment: An image of your code... really? From the sound of your description it appears that the request is working fine, so the error must be in the logic of your `Employee` controller where the username check is not working correctly.

Comment: Show your controller code!! and instead of attaching image, you should try adding relevant code..

Comment: You have a condition there `if (username.length >= 3)`, so its not just *"any name"*.

Comment: your success function also says if the username is not in use the say it already exists. I think you have that logic backwards. if (data.UserNameinUse =="false")

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is returning a single boolean value. Your JS code is expecting an object returned with a boolean property called `UserNameinUse`. You either need to amend your C# code to return that object:

```
return Json(new { UserNameinUse = UserNameinUse });
```

*Or* change your JS to work with a single value being returned, by removing `dataType: 'json'` and changing the `if` condition:

```
if (data == 'True') {
```

The former is by far the better practice.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept and/or upvote the answer.